# Issue iterating through string array - passing filepath Selenium

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I created a method to (after searching this site) enter a file path into the windows file manager.  This worked great but I wanted to expand my test case to loop through an array of file locations and pass test files to the web app to test if they are properly handled.

I'm running into an issue where on the second pass(I have 2 test files) the windows handler method doesn't want to enter the file name. Can someone scan over my code to point me in the right direction.

Here is the windows file manager method:

```
public class WindowsFileSystemHandler {
String filepath;

public void enterfilepath(String pfilepath) throws Exception{

    filepath = pfilepath;

    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filepath);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss,   null);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    //robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    //robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}

}
```

Here is the test:

```
    WindowsFileSystemHandler file = new WindowsFileSystemHandler();
        String[] fileloc = {"d:\\JW\\testfiles\\scribbles.txt", "d:\\JW\\testfiles\\earth_large_file_size.jpg"} ;
        for(int i =0 ; i<2; i++){

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        try {
            //WindowsFileSystemHandler file = new WindowsFileSystemHandler();
                    file.enterfilepath(fileloc[i]);
                    System.out.println(fileloc[i]);
                    System.out.println(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String testfiletype = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='SFI_control']/div[2]/div[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println(testfiletype);
        ProfilePage.is_file_validation_successful(testfiletype);
    }//end of for loop
```

Incidently the console output is as follows:

```
d:\JW\testfiles\scribbles.txt
0
Invalid file type.
 true
 Test to see if system correctly rejects invalid file type was successful
d:\JW\testfiles\earth_large_file_size.jpg
1
Invalid file type.
 true
Test to see if system correctly rejects invalid file type was successful
```

Is probably something silly Im missing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.  Bassically I moved the statement:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id, 'd2l_1_3_')]")).click();
```

to be within the for loop and that cleared up my issue.  Silly mistake.

Funny thing is I found a bug with the system under test with this method in that the previous error messages were not being cleared after each file upload.